# Using NSLocalNotification for multiple reminders

Tags: swift, core-data, nsdate, localnotification

I am creating a reminder based app and my only problem right now is being able to implement reminders on my app.

Basically the user is presented with a UITableView where the user can add events and I'd like to fire these dates with a notification to the user reminding them of the event on a date saved to **Core Data.**

At this time, I still do not understand how NSLocalNotification works an I have heard some users here say how apple only allows 64 notifications to be processed at a time and I only managed to create 1 but when creating another event, It is down to 0 and randomly goes back to 1 event when I debug my app with the

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications?`

and I can see the notification I set but not the other ones.

Any sample app in swift would greatly help me understand how I can set multiple notifications to add, edit, delete them.

Thanks in advance and happy coding

Comment: Any reason you can't add the events to the main device calendar?

Comment: How would I go about that? I am completely new to LocalNotifications. Do you have an example app that does this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to tackle this is to just create notifications and schedule them. If you want to remove specific notifications you will have to hold on to their references and persist them across app launches, however you can always remove all the currently scheduled notifications with `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()`

This is an example of scheduling a notification to fire once a day at the same time for 5 days:

```
let secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 24
for i in 1...5 {
  var dayString = "\(i) days"
  if i == 1 {
    dayString = "\(i) day"
  }

  let notification = UILocalNotification()
  notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeInterval: Double(i * secondsInADay), sinceDate: NSDate())
  notification.alertBody = "It has been \(dayString) since you last opened the app."
  notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

  if notification.fireDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow > 0 {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
  }
}
```

Also, you are correct, each app is given a queue for local notifications that have yet to fire. That queue can hold 64 individual notifications (a repeating notification counts as only 1 of those 64).

Comment: How would I handle a case where the dates are not hard coded, but rather set with a date picker? Basically i have an app that has a date picker that saves this date into core data and what i been doing, is fetching the instance of core data date and putting it in the fireDate and it does not work sometimes

Comment: Than the issue is not with setting the notification, but rather with pulling the date from core data. Have you tried setting a breakpoint before the date is retrieved from core data and seeing what value is being retrieved?